# Idiomatic way of parsing multiple types of request bodies (express)

Tags: express, mime-types, body-parser

I'm trying to find the best way of parsing the request body of multiple (some non-json) mime types.

Let's say I have a simple app like this:

```
const app = express()
app.use(express.json())

app.post('/test', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json(req.body)
})
```

How would I handle both of these requests and get the proper request body?

```
fetch('/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: YAML.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }),
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/yaml',
  },
})

fetch('/test', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ foo: 'bar' }),
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json',
  },
})
```

Do I need to write body parsers from scratch? Can I even do this as express seems to not expose the raw body after the json bodyparser has ran?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not searched for body parsers that support YAML.

`express.json()` consumes the incoming request stream only if the request has `Content-Type: application/json`. So you can add middleware that parses YAML into JSON after that:

```js
const yaml = require("js-yaml");
const {Writable} = require("stream");
app.use(express.json(), function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.get("content-type").startsWith("text/yaml")) {
    var buffers = [];
    req.pipe(new Writable({
      write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        buffers.push(chunk);
        callback();
      },
      final(callback) {
        try {
          req.body = yaml.load(Buffer.concat(buffers).toString());
          next();
        } catch(e) {
          next(e);
        }
      }
    }))
  } else
    next();
});
```

Note that this does not deal with compressed request payloads.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer got me problems with the regular body parsers: json ,url encoded, etc because I needed yaml and json bodies. So I created this one:

```
const yaml = require("js-yaml");
const {
    Writable
} = require("stream");

class MultiParserMiddleware {

    parser() {
        return function(req, res, next) {

            var buffers = [];
            req.pipe(new Writable({
                write(chunk, encoding, callback) {
                    buffers.push(chunk);
                    callback();
                },
                final(callback) {
                    var fullBodyString;
                    try {
                        fullBodyString = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();
                    } catch (e) {
                        return next(e);
                    }

                    if (req.get("content-type").startsWith("text/yaml")) {
                        try {
                            req.body = yaml.load(fullBodyString);
                            return next();
                        } catch (e) {
                            return next(e);
                        }
                    } else if (req.get("content-type").startsWith("application/json")) {
                        try {
                            req.body = JSON.parse(fullBodyString);
                            return next();
                        } catch (e) {
                            return next(e);
                        }
                    } else if (req.get("content-type").startsWith("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")) {
                        try {
                            req.body = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams(fullBodyString));
                            return next();
                        } catch (e) {
                            return next(e);
                        }
                    } else {
                        console.log("unsupported content-type:" + req.get("content-type") + ". req.body will containg the original body as simple string")
                        req.body = fullBodyString;
                        next();
                    }

                }
            }))
        }
    }

}

module.exports = MultiParserMiddleware
```

And in my main configuration, I did not need more parser, just one

```
const app = express();
var multiParserMiddleware = new MultiParserMiddleware();
app.use(multiParserMiddleware.parser());
```